# Проблема PYTHONPATH в Kubuntu

Tags: python, linux

Пытаюсь настроить переменную PYTHONPATH через файл .bashrc. В sys.path путь добавляется, но при попытке запустить код

```
python3 my_file.py
```

через консоль всё равно выдаёт ошибку

```
python3: can't open file 'my_file.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

В PYTHONPATH добавил именно путь где лежит файл а не путь самого файла. Помогите исправить

Comment: PYTHONPATH хранит каталоги, в которых ищутся **модули**, а не файлы.

Comment: Если файл является корректным модулем (а скорее всего является), то можно запустить модуль командой вроде `python -m my_file`

Comment: Сработало. Но мне интересно почему ```python3  my_file.py``` не работает ?

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос я написал в первом комментарии.